# Table pop-up in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to create tables similar to the tables found on http://spring.io/docs are created? I am specially interested in the "pop-up" after a click on an item.

Comment: This looks just like a little css combined with 3 lines of javascript to trigger the class from open to close on those items.

Comment: If you look at the code, these are treated like dropdowns, with a position:absolute. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using jQuery:

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="label">Label 1</div>
    <div class="dropdown">More info about label 1</div>
</div>
```

You have items, with a label and a dropdown. The dropdowns are set to `display:none` and have a position absolute, to allow them to overlap other items.

**CSS**

```
.item{
    position:relative; /*Your dropdowns will relate to their parent item*/
}

.dropdown{
    /* ...some styles... */
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Then, with jQuery, you can toggle a class `.open` on the items, which will allow you to display the dropdown on demand.

**CSS**

```
.open .dropdown{
    display:block;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.item').on('click',function(){
    //if this item is already open
    if($(this).hasClass('open'))
    {   //close it
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    }
    else
    {   //or close everything and open this one
        $('.item').removeClass('open');
        $(this).addClass('open');
    }
});
```

Or, if you want a shorter version:

```
$('.item').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open').siblings().removeClass('open');
});
```

### JS Fiddle demo

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example. So there is no standard library for doing this but CSS and Jquery are sufficient.

Comment: I suppose there are libraries for doing this, with far more options! I just thought you wanted to know how it works to do it yourself. If you are looking for cool Javascript/CSS3 effects, check out [**Codrops**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/), they have tons of them and you can download the codes. They might have something similar to this, look through the site.